# How to solve the error: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' with FLASK-MAIL?

Tags: python-3.x, flask

In one of my FLASK projects, I use flask-mail to send emails. I tried to attach a log file to the mail but I receive an error: `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`. Here is the complete error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-37:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
    File "/home/Tobin/Documents/PYTHON-PROJECTS/FLASK CHAOS V1/app/email.py", line 7, in send_async_email
mail.send(msg)
    File "/home/Tobin/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 492, in send
message.send(connection)
    File "/home/Tobin/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 427, in send
connection.send(self)
    File "/home/Tobin/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 190, in send
message.as_bytes() if PY3 else message.as_string(),
    File "/home/Tobin/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 385, in as_bytes
    return self._message().as_bytes()
    File "/home/Tobin/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 349, in _message
    f = MIMEBase(*attachment.content_type.split('/'))
    TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Here is my code:

```
from threading import Thread
from flask_mail import Message
from app import app, mail

def send_async_email(app, msg):
    with app.app_context():
        mail.send(msg)

def send_email(subject, sender, recipients, text_body):
    msg = Message(subject, sender=sender, recipients=recipients)
    msg.body = text_body
    with app.open_resource("../logs/chaos.log") as fp:
        msg.attach(b'../logs/chaos.log', fp.read())
    Thread(target=send_async_email, args=(app, msg)).start()
```

I read in a previous post that it was not possible to open a file in binary mode and treat it as str. One solution would be to use a byte object (`msg.attach(b'../logs/chaos.log', fp.read())`). but that does not seem to solve my problem. apparently there is an essential notion that escapes me, so how to solve this bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are supplying wrong arguments to `msg.attach()`. See the [API](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Mail/#flask_mail.Message.attach) for the correct parameters. The first argument should be a filename, second a content type, third the data. So the call should read something like this:

```
with app.open_resource("../logs/chaos.log") as fp:
    msg.attach('chaos.log', 'text/plain', fp.read())
```